# How to iterate through nested arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have data for a table of contents:

```
array = [
  ['Chapter 1', 'Numbers', 1],
  ['Chapter 2', 'Letters', 72],
  ['Chapter 3', 'Variables', 118]
]
```

I am trying to display the contents of the array as a table like this:

```
Chapter 1     Numbers       1
Chapter 2     Letters      72
Chapter 3     Variables   118
```

Here is my code:

```
lineWidth = 80
col1Width = lineWidth/4
col2Width = lineWidth/2
col3Width = lineWidth/4

array.each do |i|
  puts i[0].to_s.ljust(col1Width) + puts i[1].to_s.ljust(col2Width) + puts i[2].to_s.ljust(col3Width)
end
```

The problem is I keep getting this error:

```
chapter7-arrays.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    puts i[0] + puts i[1] + puts i[2]
                      ^
chapter7-arrays.rb:48: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
    puts i[0] + puts i[1] + puts i[2]
```

All help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is almost correct. The issue is that you are concatenating multiple `puts` call, whereas you should concatenate the `String` arguments, and use a single `puts` call.

```
array = [['Chapter 1', 'Numbers', 1],['Chapter 2', 'Letters', 72],['Chapter 3', 'Variables', 118]]

lineWidth = 80
col1Width = lineWidth/4
col2Width = lineWidth/2
col3Width = lineWidth/4

array.each do |i|
    puts i[0].to_s.ljust(col1Width) +
         i[1].to_s.ljust(col2Width) +
         i[2].to_s.ljust(col3Width)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, Simone! That was embarrassingly "obvious". I am learning to program and this is an interesting phenomena: sometimes the harder I try to solve something, the harder it gets to see the "obvious". It is probably essential to give the brain a rest more frequently...

Comment: Since columns 0 and 1 are already strings, there is no need to call `to_s` on them. The `puts` would reduce to `i[0].ljust(col1Width) + i[1].ljust(col2Width) + i[2].ljust(col3Width)`

Comment: @DanielCukier `to_s` is required for the third index, otherwise you'll try to call `ljust` on a Fixnum.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti exactly. I forgot to put in code. Here is the right one: `i[0].ljust(col1Width) + i[1].ljust(col2Width) + i[2].to_s.ljust(col3Width)`

Answer (score 1):

I've added an explanation according to request from **dgilperez**

We have an array of sub-arrays with three elements in each.
And we have three different formatting values for each item in a sub-array.
It is convenient to store formatting values in an array too.

```
lines = [lineWidth/4, lineWidth/2, lineWidth/4]
```

Now we need to manage a loop for each sub-array

```
array.each do |i| 
  i.map
end
```

...and we need an index of the current element to get respective formatting value.

```
array.each do |i| 
  i.map.with_index
end
```

Now we implement a block which is executed for each item **z** of sub-array

```
i.map.with_index{|z, index| z.to_s.ljust(lines[index])}
```

... and **index** is in a range [0,1,2]. 
So for the first item we will use the first formatting value, etc

index == 0, lines[index] == lineWidth/4

index == 1, lines[index] == lineWidth/2

This block returns an array of strings because we organized a loop via function **map**. Check **map** method documentation [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map)

Now we need to concatenate all the strings into one with method **join**

```
i.map.with_index{|z, index| z.to_s.ljust(lines[index])}.join
```

And return the final string - add method **puts** before the block

```
puts i.map.with_index{|z, index| z.to_s.ljust(lines[index])}.join
```

Here is the final code

```
array = [['Chapter 1', 'Numbers', 1],['Chapter 2', 'Letters', 72],['Chapter 3', 'Variables', 118]]

lineWidth = 80
lines = [lineWidth/4, lineWidth/2, lineWidth/4]

array.each do |i| 
  puts i.map.with_index{|z, index| z.to_s.ljust(lines[index])}.join
end
```